# generate random integer with numpy WITH include constraints

Tags: python, numpy, simpy

I am working with numpy and simpy on a simulation. I simulate over a 12 months periods.

```
env.run(until=12.0)
```

I need to generate random demand values that are between 2 and 50, occuring at random moments within the 12 periods length of the env.

```
d = np.random.randint(2,50) #generate random demand values
```

now the values are passed at random intervals into the 12 months simpy environement

```
0.2     40
0.65    21
0.67    03    
1.01    4
1.1     19

...

11.4    49
11.9.   21
```

what I trying to achieve is to constraint the numpy generation to make the sure that the sum of the values generated in each period (0,1,2...) does not exceed 100

to put it in different words, i am trying to generate random quantities, at random intervals along a 12 periods axis and I am trying to make sure that the sum of these quantities for one period does not exceed a given value

I cannot find anything about it online to twick numpy randint function to do that, would someone have a hint?

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question. What is it exactly that has to have the average of 100? average over what data? Thank you

Comment: i just edit my post, I hope that it helps

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question. If you are looking for your simulation to give you an average of 100 per month, then the values on demand should not be in between [2, 50] as the maximum possible average will be 50. I think you might be looking for this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

I won't go to the math but drawing random numbers from a normal distribution, and finding the mean, will give the mean of the normal distribution, which is a parameter you can use.

Comment: I believe most random number generators are memoryless. I.e. they do not have a notion on what numbers where send previously, which is what you want to achieve that the total sum is less than a particular value. I think you can still achieve that, but not with simply an argument to the library.